# How can I use Powershell to modify an Active Directory users attributes based on Employee ID?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update users AD attributes through their `EmployeeID`, not their `SAMAccountName`. I've tried using `Set-ADUser`, but it did not work because the list I am given does not contain the accounts `sAMAccountName` as it comes from HR who do not have access to this information.

Is there a way to update the AD users attributes through their unique `employeeID`?

**My source data .csv file contains this:**

```
EmployeeID;company;department;title;country;postalCode;city;streetAddress;manager
2828;TEST1;TEST2;TestXENUser;DE;12345;MUE;Miller Street 6;chrtest
```

**My script looks like this:**

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\05042017\data.csv

$Users | ForEach-Object {

    $EmpID = $_.EmployeeID

    Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Property EmployeeID | Where {$_.EmployeeID -eq $EmpID} | Set-ADUser -company $EmployeeID.company -department $EmployeeID.department –title $EmployeeID.title –country $EmployeeID.country –postalCode $EmployeeID.postalCode –city $EmployeeID.city –streetAddress $EmployeeID.streetAddress –manager $EmployeeID.manager -WhatIf
}
```

I dont think that I have made the connection to the attributes after the `Set-ADUser` command properly. I tested things out a bit on my own, but I cannot seem to get it working.

How do i tell the `Set-ADUser` command to take the attributes from the .csv file ?
I got this working in the past, but it was like this: `ForEach $user in $Users` and not: `ForEach-Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get an object that represents the user in AD by using `get-aduser` and filtering the results based on EmployeeID and then pipe this to `set-aduser`. For example:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeid -eq '$EmpID'" | Set-ADUser <-Attribute> <Value> -WhatIf
```

You obviously need to identify the attributes and values and remove the `-whatif` switch when you're happy it's doing what you expect it to.

Based on your CSV file containing:

> EmployeeID; company; department; title; country; postalCode; city; streetAddress; manager

you could do something like this:

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\05042017\data.csv -Delimiter ';'

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeid -eq '$($User.EmployeeID)'" | Set-ADUser -company $User.company -department $User.department –title $User.title –country $User.country –postalCode $User.postalCode –city $User.city –streetAddress $User.streetAddress –manager $User.manager -WhatIf
}
```

In the above example we use a `ForEach` loop which processes each line in the CSV file (which we've loaded in to `$Users`) and creates an object of the values as `$User`. We can then refer to the properties of $User (with the . notation) for the values of the attributes we need in `Set-ADUser`.

Comment: You should edit your question and add it there rather than posting it as an answer. I'll amend my answer based on the new information, I think a `ForEach` loop will be simpler/clearer.

Comment: I have modified my answer to use a `ForEach` based on the headers of the CSV you provided. I've also simplified the way we get the user by matching in the `-filter` parameter rather than using a `where`.

Comment: An error appears: Get-ADUser : The search filter was not recognized.    line: 2, letter: 15.     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt,Microsoft.Act
   iveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Strange, it works in my environment. Try reverting to this then: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -property employeeid | where {$_.employeeid -eq $User.EmployeeID} | Set-ADUser` this will just likely take longer to run in a large AD than filtering in the `-filter` property.